# Can Jquery and HTML5 be used to store an image from user's computer in the browser cache?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to allow users to preview what their image would look like as the background of a div.
I do not want to have them upload the image to my server, but rather to store it in their local cache and have Jquery grab the path and replace the background image with that of the user's choosing...

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the image to a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and use that while they are previewing the image.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an ideal use case for the File API. The File API requires [sufficient] HTML5 support only. (That is, not also jQuery.) You can write your code now and test it out in Firefox and Chrome:

http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

For mobile users, there's also PhoneGap and other 3rd party solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Not cross-browser:

```
document.getElementById('uploader').onchange = function(){
    var file = document.getElementById('uploader').files[0];

    if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        // this file is not an image.
        alert('File type not supported');
        }
    else{
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var reader = new FileReader();  
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;
            delete this;
            }
        img.onload = function(e) {
                //do your code
            }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I threw together using jQuery and the HTML5 File API. On the change for the input[type='file'], it will attempt to load the image as the src for an img tag. The File APi essentially converts the local file into a DataURI which you can then supply as the src

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkichenama/mjRQe/5/)